# How to merge by two columns aggregating one of them

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr, merge

I'm struggling on how can I make a merge using two columns. I have one dataframe containing measure about how much palette was used in some dates. I have another dataframe containing the distance travelled by the car. Then I need to merge both, and the condition to join is that: the car and the sum of the distance of one car until the date that the measure of the palette occur.
Here is a toy example:

```
#palette measure dataframe
measure = data.frame(car = c("A", "A", "A", "B"), data1 = c("20-09-2020", "15-10-2020", "13-05-2021", "20-10-2021"), palette = c(5,4,3,5))
#> measure
#  car      data1 palette 
#1   A 20-09-2020   5
#2   A 15-10-2020   4
#3   A 13-05-2021   3
#4   B 20-10-2021   5

#the distance dataframe
dist_ = data.frame(car = c("A", "C", "B", "A", "A", "A"), data2 = c("20-09-2020", "14-05-2020", "20-10-2021", "10-01-2021", "11-01-2021", "13-01-2021"), distance = c(10, 20, 10, 5, 3,8))
#> dist_
# car      data2 distance
#1   A 20-09-2020       10
#2   C 14-05-2020       20
#3   B 20-10-2021       10
#4   A 10-01-2021        5
#5   A 11-01-2021        3
#6   A 13-01-2021        8

#for result I'd like something like
#  car      data1 palette distance
#1   A 20-09-2020   5       10
#2   A 15-10-2020   4       0
#3   A 13-05-2020   3       16
#4   B 20-10-2021   5       10
```

Note that the distance are summed until I have a date that the palette are measured. So I can say that a car has covered a distance of 16 km and its palette is 3 cm.

I thought that I could use something like `merge(x = measure, y = dist_, by.x=c("car", "date1"), by.y=c("car", "data2"),all.x = T)`, but I don't know how to sum the distance values until the date of the pallete measure for a specif car.

Any hint on how could I do that?

Comment: `16` is the sum of the three distances `(5 + 3 + 8)` related to the dates of `A` until  `A 13-05-2021 3` occur

Comment: If this is "dates of `A` until `A 13-05-2021 3` occur", why are we ignoring `A 20-09-2020` with distance 10 such that it should be `(10 + 5 + 3 + 8)`?

Comment: No, because we already included `A 20-09-2020` with distance `10` in `A 20-09-2020 5`, as they have the same date. They are displayed in line 1 of the results

Comment: So in `dist_` you have a total of `26` for car A and in the result you have a total of `36` for car A. Why then is `A 20-09-2020` with distance `10` being counted for both   `A 20-09-2020 5` and `A 15-10-2020 4`

Comment: @JR96 you're right, this value should be 0, or an NA. I just corrected the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

result <- left_join(measure, dist_, by = c("car")) %>% 
  mutate(across(c("data1", "data2"), dmy)) %>% 
  filter(data1 >= data2) %>% 
  group_by(car, data2) %>% 
  mutate(threshold = min(data1)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(data1 == threshold) %>% 
  group_by(car, data1, palette)%>% 
  summarise(distance = sum(distance))

result
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   car, data1 [3]
  car   data1      palette distance
  <chr> <date>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1 A     2020-09-20       5       10
2 A     2021-05-13       3       16
3 B     2021-10-20       5       10
```

If you want to keep the non-matches you could then rejoin with `measure` like so:

```
result.final <- measure %>% 
  mutate(data1 = dmy(data1))%>% 
  left_join(result, by = c("car", "data1", "palette")) 

result.final
  car      data1 palette distance
1   A 2020-09-20       5       10
2   A 2020-10-15       4       NA
3   A 2021-05-13       3       16
4   B 2021-10-20       5       10
```

Comment: Nice, though you could replace `library(tidyverse)` with `library(dplyr)`, since you don't use anything else in `tidyverse`.

Comment: Yes, actually I need all the rows in `measure`.  I'll try out this solution!

Comment: Edited to add all rows in measure.

Comment: @JR96, in my real case, I have others measures like `distance`, in this case I just summarize them, like you did in the last line of the code? Something like: `summarise(distance1 = sum(distance1), distance2 = sum(distance2))`

Comment: Correct. Though, depending on the number of a expressions within your `summarise()` call, it may be cleanest to use `across()` similar to how I used it above.